# Mysql - speed up select query from 2 million rows

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have a table like below,

```
Field    Type      Null Key Default               Extra

id       bigint(11) NO  PRI NULL                  auto_increment
deviceId bigint(11) NO  MUL NULL        
value    double     NO      NULL        
time    timestamp   YES MUL 0000-00-00 00:00:00
```

It has more than 2 million rows. When I run `select * from tableName;` It takes more than 15 mins.

When I run `select value,time from sensor_value where time > '2017-05-21 04:47:48' and deviceId>=812;` It takes more than 45 sec to load.

**Note :**  512 has more than 92514 rows.
Even I have added index for column like below,

```
ALTER TABLE `sensor_value` 
 ADD INDEX `IDX_FIELDS1_2` (`time`, `deviceId`) ;
```

How do I make select query fast?(load in 1sec) Am I doing indexing wrong?

Comment: Pls include the results of the explain of your select.

Comment: Your covering index probably should be deviceId THEN time . As that can probably usefully cut down the records more before resorting to the range of times.

Comment: Please give some more info like cardinality of an index which you have created and explain the statement.

Answer (score 2):

Only 4 columns?  Sounds like you have very little RAM, or `innodb_buffer_pool_size` is set too low.  Hence, you were seriously I/O-bound and/or swapping.

```
WHERE time > '2017-05-21 04:47:48'
  AND deviceId >= 812
```

is two ranges.  There is no thorough way to optimize that.  Either of these would help.  If you have both, the Optimizer *might* pick the better one:

```
INDEX(time)
INDEX(deviceId)
```

When using a 'secondary' index in InnoDB, the query first looks in the index BTree; when there is a match there, it has to look up in the 'data' BTree (using the `PRIMARY KEY` for lookup).

Some of the anomalous times you saw when trying `INDEX(time, deviceId)` were because the filtering kept from having to reach over into the data as often.

Do you use `id` for anything other than uniqueness?  Is the pair deviceId & time unique?  If the answers are 'no' and 'yes', then get rid of `id` and change to `PRIMARY KEY(deviceId, time)`.  Or you could swap those two columns.  What other queries do you have?

Getting rid of `id` shrinks the table some, thereby cutting down on I/O.

Comment: After I set innodb_buffer_pool_size=1073741824 in my.cnf file, It loads in 5 secs.

Comment: How much RAM do you have?

Comment: I have total 8GB RAM but 2 GB free usage, but It taking 84% RAM uage after I set buffe_size to 1GB. I think still its not a good solution to increasing upto 1GP.

Answer (score 1):

When using combined index usually you must use equality operator on first column and then you can use range criteria on second column. So I recommend you change the order of columns in your index like this:

```
ALTER TABLE `sensor_value` 
 ADD INDEX `IDX_FIELDS1_2` (`deviceId`, `time`) ;
```

then change to use equal sign for `deviceId`(use `deviceId=812` not `deviceId>=812`):

```
select value,time from sensor_value where time > '2017-05-21 04:47:48' and deviceId=812;
```

I hope it could help.

2 million records is not much for Mysql and it is normal to get result in less than 1 sec for 1 billion records if you do the right things.

Comment: But, if OP really needs `>= 812`, not of this is relevant.

Comment: It is important to narrow down the records correctly. if we have little count of rows in `>= 812` then index can be useful. But normally we can't use range for both columns of index and expect good performance. In that situation using separate indexes would be better.

Comment: MySQL almost never uses two indexes in one `SELECT` ("index merge").  When it does, it is rather costly -- creating two temp tables, 'intersecting' them, then finally looking up the rows.

Comment: @RickJames You are right but (as you mentioned in your answer) it can help Mysql to choose better index according the query criteria.